# Why doesn't this query select any rows

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this SQL?
It seems like it should work, but it doesn't.

utc_time is a datetime field.

```
SELECT id
FROM `foo`
WHERE utc_time > now() 
AND utc_time <= DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL 24 day);
```

Explain says that the Where clause is impossible.

utc_time is type datetime. Here is a sample utc_time value: 2011-06-21 00:45:00

Comment: What does MySQL tell you? Without an error I'm going to go ahead and blame gremlins or satan or something.

Comment: Please give an example value for utc_time and now() where you think it should be selected, but it isn't.

Comment: is utc_time a column in your query, or are you calling the function `utc_time()` is so, it ain't ruby, you need the `()`. If its the name of the column, i bet you have it set as a datetime...

Comment: Can you post the tables schema?  (`create table` statement)

Comment: So it doesn't work .... eh ... please tell us HOW it doesn't work.

Comment: May I suggest changing it into: `SELECT id
FROM foo
WHERE utc_time > now() 
AND utc_time <= DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL 24 day);`

Comment: What is the datatype of utc_time? I'm assuming it's a DATE/DATETIME or similar. Anything else probably wont work.

Comment: "That still doesn't work" .... eh .... HOW doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utc_time()` is a [built-in function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Even without the brackets, `utc_time` still returns the current UTC time.

Escape the column named `utc_time`. This works (I tested it):

```
SELECT id
FROM `foo`
WHERE `utc_time` > now() 
AND `utc_time` <= DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL 24 day);
```

Yet another example of why it's a bad idea to use reserved words or function names as column/table names.

Comment: You got it!!! Thanks so much. That was driving me crazy. Time to change that column name. :-)